# Signing messages using MetaMask in Flutter

Tags: flutter, metamask, wallet-connect

I am using [walletconnect_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/walletconnect_dart) package to connect my Flutter app to MetaMask which works fine. But I want the user to sign a message in MetaMask and get the signature. How can I do that in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is your solution**

```
  ElevatedButton signMessage() {
return ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      String? signmessage = "Sign Message";
      List<String?> params = [signmessage, walletAddress];
      String method = "personal_sign";

      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(walletConnect.session.toUri()),
          mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
     final _signature = await walletConnect.sendCustomRequest(
        method: method,
        params: params,
      );

      print( _signature); 
    },
    child: const Text("SIGN MESSAGE"));}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).